# Bootstrap tags:Type ahead is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I m trying to make an autocomplete tag fiels in `yii` with the help of `bootstrap tag`. The tag field is working,but typeahead is not.

My field:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'existing_control')
->textInput(
    [
    'max-width'=>'10px',

        'id'=>'vuln'.$model->v_id,
        //'data-role'=>'tagsinput',
        'name'=>$model->v_id,
        'placeholder'=>'Type each here and press enter',]
            )
        ?>
```

My script:

```
  $('input[type=text][id="vuln<?php echo $model->v_id;?>"]').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
   source: ["Amsterdam","Washington","Sydney","Beijing","Cairo"],
  }
  });
```

I got an error like `TypeError: a is undefined` in `bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js`.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but the problem may have been "typeahead:" versus "typeaheadjs:".  The first is identified in the code as "Typeahead Bootstrap version 2.3.2" while the second is "typeahead.js", so it depends upon which version of tagsinput was downloaded and possibly which version of Bootstrap they were using.